# how can i modify the threads to print " hello world again" ? in C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, mutex

how can I force the three threads to print " hello world again" using lock_mutex or sleep function ? im done with it ...

```
/* t2.c
       synchronize threads through mutex and conditional variable 
       To compile use: gcc -o t2 t2.c -lpthread 
    */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void hello(); // define three routines called by threads
void world();
void again(); /*new statment*/

/* global variable shared by threads */
pthread_mutex_t mutex; // mutex
pthread_cond_t done_hello; // conditional variable
int done = 0; // testing variable

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pthread_t tid_hello, // thread id
        tid_world, tid_again;

    /*  initialization on mutex and cond variable  */
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    pthread_cond_init(&done_hello, NULL);

    pthread_create(&tid_hello, NULL, (void*)&hello, NULL); //thread creation
    pthread_create(&tid_world, NULL, (void*)&world, NULL); //thread creation
    pthread_create(&tid_again, NULL, (void*)&again, NULL); //thread creation/*new statment*/
    /* main waits for the three threads to finish by order */
    pthread_join(tid_hello, NULL);

    pthread_join(tid_world, NULL);

    pthread_join(tid_again, NULL); /*new statment*/

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void hello()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    printf(" hello");

    fflush(stdout); // flush buffer to allow instant print out
    done = 2;

    pthread_cond_signal(&done_hello); // signal world() thread
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); // unlocks mutex to allow world to print
    return;
}

void world()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    /* world thread waits until done == 1. */
    while (done == 1)
        pthread_cond_wait(&done_hello, &mutex);

    printf(" world");
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); // unlocks mutex
    return;
}

void again() /*new function*/
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    /* again thread waits until done == 0. */
    while (done == 0)
        pthread_cond_wait(&done_hello, &mutex);

    printf(" again");
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); // unlocks mutex
    return;
}
```

Comment: Do not cast function pointers  to `void *`, just use the correct prototype `void *hello(void *)`

Comment: when i use your prototype this error happen t2.c:31:37: error: expected expression
  pthread_create (&tid_hello, NULL, void *hello(void *)

Comment: The `pthread_create` call should look like this: `pthread_create(&tid_hello, NULL, hello, NULL);` and the function `void *hello(void *) { pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. But you should use several `pthread_cond_t` signals:

- one when `"hello"` has been printed
- one when `"world"` has been printed.

Effectively, from [man `pthread_cond_wait()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait):

> The effect of using more than one mutex for concurrent pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait() operations on the same condition variable is undefined; that is, a condition variable becomes bound to a unique mutex when a thread waits on the condition variable, and this (dynamic) binding shall end when the wait returns.

Each `world` and `again` functions has to wait for its own signal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void * hello(void*);                   
void * world(void*);
void * again(void*);                   

/* global variable shared by threads */
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;          
pthread_cond_t done_hello = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;      
pthread_cond_t done_world = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;      

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t threads[3];

    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, hello, NULL);    
    pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, world, NULL);    
    pthread_create(&threads[2], NULL, again, NULL);    

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void * hello(void* foo)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        printf(" hello");
        fflush(stdout);             
        pthread_cond_signal(&done_hello);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);       
    return NULL;
}

void * world(void* foo)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_wait(&done_hello, &mutex);
        printf(" world");
        fflush(stdout);
        pthread_cond_signal(&done_world);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);       
    return NULL;
}

void * again(void* foo)
{                               
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_wait(&done_world, &mutex);
        printf(" again");
        fflush(stdout);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: "But you have to use several pthread_cond_t signals" is not entirely correct. It can be solved in several ways (including using a single pthread_cond_t).

Comment: @4386427: I was not sure when I read the `pthread_cond_wait` man page. Two differents thread can wait for the same `pthread_cond_t` without problem?

Comment: although there is some time slicing but , great answer and explination from you sit

Comment: Two threads can wait on the same but in that case `pthread_cond_broadcast` may be needed

Comment: That isn't how to use condvars.  The original was closer.  A condvar has no memory, so if one thread signals it when no other thread is waiting, nobody will ever know.

Answer (score 0):

To use condvars properly, consider this:

```
void *thread(void *arg)
{
        static char str[] = { "hello", "world", "again" };
        int value = (int)(intptr_t)arg;
        /* wait for the condition (done == value) to be true */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while (done != value) {
                pthread_cond_wait(&done_hello, &mutex);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        /* release all locks to decrease latency during our work */
        printf(" %s", str[value]);
        /* reacquire the lock to update done */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        done++;
        /* notify anybody that might be waiting for done */
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&done_hello);
        /* permit others to continue */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        return NULL;
}
```

It is a bit different from yours, but having all the threads run the same code builds confidence that the code is correct, and reduces the effort to debug it when it isn't.   Note how the condition is used:  `lock(); while (!condition) wait(); unlock();` and `lock(); setcondition(); broadcast(); unlock();` The order of `broadcast(); unlock();` doesn't matter provided you do nothing between them.  Pick a convention, and stick to it; when you need to break it, it serves as a clue that something is going on.